# how to send mail from mysql using stored-procedures?

Tags: mysql, email, stored-procedures

Is there any mail packages available in mysql? 
I am using phpmyadmin tool to manage mysql Db.
I want to send email using stored-procedures in mysql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is not and You should not do this because it can affect mysql performance.

My advice is to write a simple script that send e-mails according to data from table.